# Clearing default values upon submit

Tags: jquery

I'm having problems clearing the default values of the input fields in my simple registration form.  They were generated by the jquery-inputfocus library.  Here is the snippet in question.  The entire code is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brohjoe/ExcG7/

Can someone tell me what is the problem here?  Thanks.

```
var fields = new Array(
            $('#firstname').val(),
            $('#middlename').val(),
            $('#lastname').val()

        );
        var tr = $('#second_step #leftSummary tr');
        tr.each(function(){
            var valueL = $(this).val();

           //problem with logic here!
           if(valueL == field_values[$(this).attr('id')]) {
               $this.val('')
            } else {
               $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[$(this).index()])
           }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using [placeholders](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) instead of setting the value?